# Automatic counter in Ruby for each?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I want to use a for-each and a counter:

```
i=0
for blah in blahs
    puts i.to_s + " " + blah
    i+=1
end
```

Is there a better way to do it?

**Note:** I don't know if `blahs` is an array or a hash, but having to do `blahs[i]` wouldn't make it much sexier. Also I'd like to know how to write `i++` in Ruby.

---

Technically, Matt's and Squeegy's answer came in first, but I'm giving best answer to paradoja so spread around the points a bit on SO. Also his answer had the note about versions, which is still relevant (as long as my Ubuntu 8.04 is using Ruby 1.8.6).

---

Should've used `puts "#{i} #{blah}"` which is a lot more succinct.

Comment: There is no increment operator in Ruby. The n+=1 you wrote up there is the closest equivalent. It would have to be syntactic sugar for n+=1, which is itself shorthand for n=n+1. The idea of ++ was rejected because it hides the fact that you're reassigning the variable. http://rubyurl.com/Dsb1

Comment: Nice! Thanks Chuck. I was forced to learn ++i and i++ in Java, so I just thought it would always be there.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

As people have said, you can use

```
each_with_index
```

but if you want indices with an iterator different to "each" (for example, if you want to map with an index or something like that) you can concatenate enumerators with the each_with_index method, or simply use with_index:

```
blahs.each_with_index.map { |blah, index| something(blah, index)}

blahs.map.with_index { |blah, index| something(blah, index) }
```

This is something you can do from ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is new in 1.9.

Comment: Well spotted. Actually, it's also in 1.8.7, but it's something worth adding.

Comment: why am I on Ruby 1.8.6 if I just installed the whole thing on Ubuntu? Is 1.8.7 experimental/beta?

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you using? In Intrepid there's 1.8.7. It's the last stable version ( http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ ). You may, however, monkeypatch ruby 1.8.6 to have the same behavior (see http://www.strictlyuntyped.com/2008/09/ruby-187s-enumerator-class.html ).

Comment: Hmmm... I ran sudo apt-get install ruby irb rdoc on my Ubuntu and it got 1.8.6. How should I be doing it? Running Ubuntu 8.04.1, not sure if that's Incredibly Intrepid or Hardly Jeronimo (that joke only works with the second half in Spanish, unfortunately).

Comment: Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy :) ) shipped with ruby 1.8.6. Ubuntu's policy is to not update packages (except security issues and things like that) so in the official repos it's the latest. If you want to run ruby 1.8.7 you follow: http://www.vanutsteen.nl/2008/06/29/installing-ruby-187-and-guessnet-on-hardy/

Comment: Argh... "you follow", well, it doesn't matter.

Yoy can also install ruby from source, and possibly there are other alternatives for installing the latest ruby in your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I got tired of the distribution being behind so I started using rvm to manage my Ruby installation on Ubuntu and Linux Mint.

Answer (score 56):

```
[:a, :b, :c].each_with_index do |item, i|
  puts "index: #{i}, item: #{item}"
end
```

You can't do this with for.  I usually like the more declarative call to each personally anyway.  Partly because its easy to transition to other forms when you hits the limit of the for syntax.

Comment: Nice, I see the point about the limits with the for syntax. I have to get used to blocks with multiple parameters.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it's `collection.each` to do loops, and then `each_with_index` to get the index.

You probably ought to read a Ruby book because this is fundamental Ruby and if you don't know it, you're going to be in big trouble (try: http://poignantguide.net/ruby/).

Taken from the Ruby source code:

```
 hash = Hash.new
 %w(cat dog wombat).each_with_index {|item, index|
   hash[item] = index
 }
 hash   #=> {"cat"=>0, "wombat"=>2, "dog"=>1}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Didn't mean to be "mean" about the .each block -- these are fundamental ruby constructs and learning them on the fly will be really, really painful. :) Best to bite the bullet and spend a few hours reading!

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have the new version of `each_with_index`, you can use the [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003138) method to pair indexes with elements:

```
blahs = %w{one two three four five}
puts (1..blahs.length).zip(blahs).map{|pair|'%s %s' % pair}
```

which produces:

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
```

Comment: Where can I find this code from your answer `'%s %s' % [1, "two"]` in the Ruby docs? Thanks for your help and for conserving vertical space by using one line for zipping and mapping.

Comment: In this context, the %-sign operator is a method of the String class. You can read about it at http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000770. Or you can type ri String#% at a command prompt. Or you can type ri % to see all of the documented classes that recognize it, e.g., the more familiar meaning at ri Fixnum#%.

Answer (score 4):

As to your question about doing `i++`, well, you cannot do that in Ruby.  The `i += 1` statement you had is exactly how you're supposed to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get index of ruby for each, then you can use

```
.each_with_index
```

Here is an example to show how `.each_with_index` works:

```
range = ('a'..'z').to_a
length = range.length - 1
range.each_with_index do |letter, index|
    print letter + " "
    if index == length
        puts "You are at last item"
    end
end
```

This will print:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z You are at last item
```

Answer (score 2):

The [enumerating enumerable](http://www.globalnerdy.com/tag/enumerable/) series is pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

If `blahs` is a class that mixes in Enumerable, you should be able to do this:

```
blahs.each_with_index do |blah, i|
  puts("#{i} #{blah}")
end
```