# Finding out current index in EACH loop (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic counter in Ruby for each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533837/automatic-counter-in-ruby-for-each)

I want to find out the current index while i am in the each loop. how do i do so?

```
X=[1,2,3]

X.each do |p|
 puts "current index..."
end
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533837/automatic-counter-in-ruby-for-each

Answer (score 332, accepted):

```
X.each_with_index do |item, index|
  puts "current_index: #{index}"
end
```

Comment: This solution is clearer and more concise than what's in the duplicate.

Comment: You can actually do this in the for loop, `for each,index in X.each_with_index; ...; end`

Comment: Why does ruby's author bother to introduce each_with_index...

Answer (score 18):

`x.each_with_index { |v, i| puts "current index...#{i}" }`

Comment: `i` should be the second parameter to the block

Comment: how to get index value without each_with_index method?