# Define a new type of for loop in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to work out how to define a custom `for` loop in R, or if that's even possible.

#### Examples

A couple of things that would be nice to have are

- something equivalent to ruby's [`each_with_index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846323), as well as
- A `for` loop that completely ignores exceptions (without having to [manually code exception handling into the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55937737)).

Is it possible to define a new kind of for loop in R (and if so, how), or is this an inherent limitation of the language and hence not something that can be done?

#### Use cases

Here's a random example of how `for_each_with_index` could simplify finicky arithmetic

Suppose we want to scrape the 36th to the 55th article from a website and assign the output to a position in a list. This works well

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
articles <- vector(mode = "list", length = 20)
for(i in 36:55) {
  paste0("Scraping article ", i) %>% print
  articles[[i - 35]] <- read_html(paste0("http://afr.herokuapp.com/articles/", i)) %>% 
             html_nodes("p") %>% html_text %>% paste0(collapse="/n")
           }
```

But we see some finicky arithmetic (`36:55`, `i - 35` etc) that could theoretically be abstracted away through `for_each_with_index` enumerating over each element of the `articles` object, like so:

```
# NOT ACTUAL R CODE

library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
articles <- vector(mode = "list", length = 20)
for_each_with_index(articles, i) {
  paste0("Scraping article ", i) %>% print
  articles[[i]] <- read_html(paste0("http://afr.herokuapp.com/articles/", i + 35)) %>% 
             html_nodes("p") %>% html_text %>% paste0(collapse="/n")
           }
```

By using `for_each_with_index`, we avoided the fiddly arithmetic . This example is very simple, but when the complexity turns up some notches i.e when we have various conditionals, nested loops etc, things get much more complex and these seemingly small improvements in clarity become more profound

Comment: @chinsoon12 I have updated the question with an example. Sorry it's a long one. I hope it makes sense

Comment: See ```lapply(36:55, function (i) {read_html(paste0(...))})```

Comment: I fail to see how `i + 35` is less finicky than `i - 35`

Comment: The essential difference is not between i + 35 and i - 35, but between using a for loop and not. For loops are highly inefficient in R, involving lots of unnecessary copying. They work just fine for looping over a small number of strings, but if you have to do computation on hundreds of thousands of records, for loops will kill your performance.

Comment: @BigFinger is wrong:  for loops are not particularly inefficient.  Like the other control constructs (if, while, etc.) they are internally function calls, just with special rules in the parser to construct the call.  If you want different semantics than for, you can define your own function, but you can't change the syntax of the language, so it will need to be done with an infix operator (like Martin Morgan's answer) or a regular function call.

Answer (score 3):

The [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/package=foreach) package provides one model

```
res = foreach(i = 1:3) %do% {
    sqrt(i)
}
```

This is using the R `%any%` construct, which is an infix operator that can be defined by the user, so

```
`%with_index%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
    ## implement ...
    Map(function(i) {
        list(i, rhs(lhs[[i]]))
    }, seq_along(lhs))
}

1:10 %with_index% sqrt
```

It has also defined the `foreach()` function to set up the right hand side. `%do%` has to be written in such a way that the implementation works for relatively general `rhs`, and this is not a trivial task.

Implementing `for_each() %with_index% {}` would probably be quite interesting, and very educational.

Comment: Very nice approach!

Answer (score 1):

1. It is best to avoid for loops in R, especially for your main
   computation. Looping in R is achieved with functions like lapply,
   sapply, mapply, tapply. These are flexible and can be customized by
   passing your own functions into them.
2. Have a look at the try() function, which you can use to wrap your code in. If you set the argument "silent" to true, errors will be ignored.

Thanks for posting an example. The solution by @HubertL is the right approach. An index is not needed in this case. If you really want to pass the index to lapply instead of the actual page number, this can be easily done:

```
my_scraper <- function(article_id){ 
  paste0("Scraping article ", article_id) %>% print
  read_html(paste0("http://afr.herokuapp.com/articles/", article_id + 35)) %>%
    html_nodes("p") %>% 
    html_text %>% 
    paste0(collapse="/n")}

articles <- lapply(1:20, my_scraper)
```

Comment: how long does it take to perform a million iterations, `system.time( for (i in 1:1000000) {} )` ? What about `lapply(1:1000000, function(i) {})` ?

Comment: Yes, that's a great question. If you put it like this, there should be no benefit to using lapply over the for loop. I need to revise my answer. In this example, read_html operates on one element of the list at a time, so there doesn't seem to be a way to optimize the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with this function:

```r
for_with_index <- function(var, index, seq, expr) {
  env <- parent.frame() # This is where evaluation takes place
  for (i in seq_along(seq)) {
    assign(as.character(substitute(index)), i, envir = env)
    assign(as.character(substitute(var)), seq[i], envir = env)
    eval(substitute(expr), envir = env)
  }
}

for_with_index(i, j, 7:9, cat("Entry ", j, " is ", i, "\n"))
#> Entry  1  is  7 
#> Entry  2  is  8 
#> Entry  3  is  9
```

If you want to use for-like syntax, it's a little harder, because you can't modify the parser.  However, after parsing, for loops are just function calls, so you can still do it if you can figure out where to put the index in the call.  One way might be to write it like this:

```r
for (i in {7:9;j}) 
  cat("Entry ", j, " is ", i, "\n")
```

That's legal syntax, but in the standard loop it wouldn't work, because `{7:9;j}` evaluates the same as `j`, which isn't what you want.  But you can write your own for loop function to handle it:

```r
`for` <- function(var, seq, expr) { 
  env <- parent.frame()
  seq <- substitute(seq)
  if (is.call(seq) && seq[[1]] == "{" && length(seq) == 3) {
    index2 <- seq[[3]]
    seq <- eval(seq[[2]], env)
    for (index in seq_along(seq)) {
      assign(as.character(substitute(var)), seq[index], envir = env)
      assign(as.character(index2), index, envir = env)
      eval(substitute(expr), envir = env)
    }
  } else {
    seq <- eval(seq, env)
    oldfor <- substitute(for (var in seq) expr, 
                         list(var = substitute(var), 
                              seq = seq, 
                              expr = substitute(expr)))
    oldfor[[1]] <- base::`for`
    eval(oldfor, env)
  }
}

for (i in 7:9) 
  print(i)
#> [1] 7
#> [1] 8
#> [1] 9

for (i in {7:9; j}) 
  cat("Entry ", j, " is ", i, "\n")
#> Entry  1  is  7 
#> Entry  2  is  8 
#> Entry  3  is  9
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Cole comment, and as mentionned by @BigFinger in their answer, you "always" should think `lapply` when you need a `for` loop:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

my_scraper <- function(article_id){ 
  paste0("Scraping article ", article_id) %>% print
  read_html(paste0("http://afr.herokuapp.com/articles/", article_id)) %>%
    html_nodes("p") %>% 
    html_text %>% 
    paste0(collapse="/n")}

articles <- lapply(36:55, my_scraper)
```

`lapply()` builds a list so you don't have to initialize it.

`lapply` is not easy to use at first, but it is very convenient. If you like `tidyverse` you can have also a look at `purr::map()`