# Rails - How to render content if the value in the CSV is TRUE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a CSV file

```
Plant_ID,Short_note,Live

YCCXXX1,Description one,TRUE
    
YCCXXX3,Description three,FALSE
```

an initializer

```rb
  require 'csv'    
  plant_table = File.read('app/assets/csv/Plant_table_(USDA_Citrus).csv')
  PlantTable.destroy_all
  csv = CSV.parse(plant_table, :headers => true)
  csv.each do |row|
    PlantTable.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
```

which render in a view component

```html
<% @plant_tables.each do |plant_table| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to plant_table.Plant_ID, plant_table %></td>
    <td>PlantX, PlantY</td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

but I want it to render these ONLY if the **LIVE** property is **TRUE**.

I want something like this

```rb
#plant_table_initializer.rb
  require 'csv'    
  plant_table = File.read('app/assets/csv/Plant_table_(USDA_Citrus).csv')
  PlantTable.destroy_all
  csv = CSV.parse(plant_table, :headers => true)
  csv.each do |row|
    if csv[row][2] == "TRUE"
    PlantTable.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
```

Comment: add next before your if like this:  `next if csv[row][2] == "TRUE"`

Comment: In your first example, row appears to be a hash. In the second you are calling csv[row][2] which doesn’t quite make sense, you wouldn’t use a hash as the key in another hash, or refer to its content by numbers. Try changing it to this: if row[“Live”] == “TRUE”

Comment: It worked with both row[2] or row["Live"]. I opted for Live because it's cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much there just syntax, remove *csv* part as we are assigning it to *row* from `csv.each do |row|`

```
if row[2] == "TRUE"
```

not

```
if csv[row][2] == "TRUE"
```

Comment: I initially thought that, but then I realised that in the first example row looks like a hash.

Comment: Oh, I'm a ruby noob. When you do: `some_var do |this|` you're hashing some_var = |this|? And making something similar to a for loop?

Comment: It's a "for each” loop copying the output to the 'this' value. 
Maybe this would also help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846313/finding-out-current-index-in-each-loop-ruby

Answer (score 1):

```
if row[2] == 'TRUE'
   render ...
end
```

Should sort you.

Comment: render crashed the app, but the other syntax was correct! Appreciate it

Comment: Odd... I'd like to investigate further, if you don't mind.

Comment: Let me know if I can be of any help

Comment: A link to your git repository would be helpful?