# Is there an alternative to using a counter variable in a each do loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm outputting a list of items from an array in Ruby. I need to output the position of each item in the array, as well as the value. I thought I was being clever by using the index of the value as I looped through the array rather then setting an temporary counter variable, but I got burned when I had an array with duplicate items. See below...

```
array = ["a","b","c","a"]
array.each do |letter|
 puts "Position: #{array.index(letter)} - Letter: #{letter}"
end

# Position: 0 - Letter: a
# Position: 1 - Letter: b
# Position: 2 - Letter: c
# Position: 0 - Letter: a    # Oops! That's not the position of that item.
```

Is below the most efficient way to generate the desired output or is there a better way that would keep the counter variable assignment contained within the each do loop?

```
array = ["a","b","c","a"]
counter = 0
array.each do |letter|
  puts "Position: #{counter} - Letter: #{letter}"
  counter += 1
end

# Position: 0 - Letter: a
# Position: 1 - Letter: b
# Position: 2 - Letter: c
# Position: 3 - Letter: a
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Automatic counter in Ruby for each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533837/automatic-counter-in-ruby-for-each)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
array = ["a","b","c","a"]
array.each_with_index do |letter,i|
  puts "Position: #{i} - Letter: #{letter}"
end
```

Also, if you will need to have this in `map` method, you can use `.with_index` *modifier*:

```
["a","b","c","a"].map.with_index { |e,i| [e,i] }

=> [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2], ["a", 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done simply by using `each_with_index`:

```
 a.each_with_index{ |o,i| puts "position #{i} - letter #{o}" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do some `times` stuff.  :)

```
array.length.times do |i|
  puts "Position: #{i} - Letter: #{array[i]}"
end
```

Note, i'm just learning Ruby -- this may be evil or something.

Comment: Generally you'll see Ruby code written to iterate directly over the array or container, rather than asking for the length. If we need an index value we'll use `each_with_index`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I didn't know about `each_with_index`.  I'd seem `times` before, though, so i used that.  TMTOWTDI and stuff.  :)