# How can I limit the number of records to load in view???

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

This code shows all the records of CommunityTopic that belongs to current Community.
How can I limit the numbers to 10 records to display here?

```
<ul>
  <% @community.community_topics.each do |topic| %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to topic.title, community_topic_path(@community, topic) %>
    <%= link_to topic.user.user_profile.nickname, community_topic_path(@community, topic) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533837/automatic-counter-in-ruby-for-each

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `limit` method:

```
<% @community.community_topics.limit(10).each do |topic| %>
```

This will only supply the first 10 elements of the collection to the block. If you want to be more sophisticated, you could use something like [will_paginate](http://rubygems.org/gems/will_paginate).

In general, such data fetching should take place in the controller. So instead of having a `@community` variable where the view gets the data from, have a `@community_topics` as well, which is prefilled with the data you want to render.

Comment: You'd better use `limit(10)`, as `take` comes from Array and all the community_topics will be fetched in memory, although only 10 will be shown.

Comment: So 'limit' eats less memory??

Comment: `limit` will change the database query to only fetch the first 10 records. `take` would trigger the query (all records) to build an array and then truncate the array to the first 10 records.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't usually do this in the view, but rather in the controller.  You can use `limit` as @Fermaref proposed, or you can use a paginator to help you out such as will_paginate or kaminari.

To move this to the controller, try something like this:

```
def some_action
  @community = Community.find(params[:id])
  @community_topics = @community.community_topics.order(:some_attribute).limit(10)
end
```

Then just use `@community_topics` in your view.  One advantage here is that you can now move this logic to a private method for reuse if needed.  You can also functionally test that `@community_topics` limits to 10 rows.

Comment: What's the reason why I shouldn't do this in view? and what if I'm showing 10 newest Topic in current Community#show? Should I use this way? If they wanna see more, then can press 'show all' and moves to CommunityTopic#index

Comment: Modifying/truncating collections in the view is considered poor design, as it makes your logic more difficult to test, debug, and refactor.  Sometimes it can't be helped, but data collection for rendering belongs in the controller wherever possible.

Comment: Okay that makes sense Thanks so much! In this case, how can you replace this to controller-based?

Comment: Updated to clarify.  Note that I added an `order` clause so the topics will return predictably - substitute `:some_attribute` for whatever makes sense in your case.  If the association is hard coded to use a specific order this won't be necessary.

Comment: You certainly can.  And that will usually be in the controller as well for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use 8.3 reorder

The reorder method overrides the default scope order. For example:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:subcategories).where(active: true).references(:subcategories).order(name: :asc).reorder('categories.name ASC', 'subcategories.name ASC')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html